# AutoMapper does not unproxy NHibernate entity

Tags: c#, nhibernate, asp.net-web-api, automapper

Consider this entity:

```
public class CondRule
{
    public virtual decimal Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual CondRuleType RuleType { get; set; }
    public virtual string Statement { get; set; }
}
```

and `CondRuleType` is:

```
public class CondRuleType
{
   public virtual int Id { get; set; }
   public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

It is obvious that there is a one to one relation between `CondRule` and `CondRuleType` entities.

Also I have `CondRuleDto`:

```
public class CondRuleDto
{
    public decimal Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public CondRuleType RuleType { get; set; }
}
```

I have mapped `CondRule` to `CondRuleDto` using `AutoMapper`:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<CondRule, CondRuleDto>();
```

When I call `Session.Get` to get `CondRule` by id and the map the result to `CondRuleDto`, AutoMapper does not resolve proxies (here `RuleType`).
Here is my code:

```
var condRule = Session.Get<CondRule>(id);
var condRuleDto = Mapper.Map<CondRuleDto>(condRule);
```

When I watch condRuleDto, `RuleType` property is a NHibernate proxy. I want `AutoMapper` to map `RuleType` proxy to a POCO. How to make this work?

**PS:** I have to mention that when I use query and use automapper's `Project`, it will result a list with no proxies (I know that `Project` make this happen. May be I need something like `Project` to use after `Session.Get`):

```
Session.Query<CondRule>().Project().To<CondRuleDto>().ToList()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Casts won't change the underlying object (i.e. your `CondRuleType` will be still a proxy even if you map its instance to another property of type `CondRuleType`).

It seems like you need to create a custom mapping where `CondRule.RuleType` is mapped creating a new instance of `CondRuleType`.

Comment: How to do that custom mapping?

Comment: @alisabzevari try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132251/how-to-handle-custom-properties-in-automapper (I'm at work and I can't try things... but it might be in the right track)

Comment: Thanks, but I want to tel automapper to unproxy every proxied object automatically. With you solution I have to define custom mapping for every reference property of every entity.

Comment: @alisabzevari With some effort I'm sure you can generalize the solution... At the end of the day, you can't expect AutoMapper to solve your scenario "as is"... I believe that it might be fixed using some reflection to introspect property types and create an instance using `Activator.CreateInstance`...

Comment: I know that I have to use reflection. The problem is I don't know where I have to write this code or how to tell automapper when it sees these classes do my operation to performa mapping

Comment: BTW your answer is correct. I have to ask another question.

Comment: @alisabzevari Maybe. BTW, have you thought about wrapping that reflection into a re-usable delegate that can be given to many automapper class maps?

Comment: I wanted to write one CreateMap for any proxy class

Comment: @alisabzevari so this is what I try to say :D you can have some helper class like `CustomMappings.UnproxyAssociations<TSource, TDestination>(T Source someObject)`... there's more hard work than this, but I want to give you the idea........