# Map two different objects with different properties

Tags: c#, .net, casting

I have a Class with set of properties for e.g.:

```
class Employee 
{
    string Id {get ; set ; }
    string Name {get ; set ; }
    string Lastname {get ; set ; }
    string email {get ; set ; }
}
```

I have another object - I get the data from some third party as API string. I used NewtonSoft Json to deserialize them. Their structure looks something like this:

```
class ThirdPartyEmployee
{
    string EmpId {get ; set ; }
    string fName {get ; set ; }
    string LName {get ; set ; }
    string emailID {get ; set ; }
    string Phonenumber {get ; set ; }
}
```

For reasons of simplicity - I cannot change the property of both the classes.

Now the question is, when I receive the json object,

```
List<Employee> obj1 = new List<Employee>();
List<ThirdPartyEmployee> obj2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ThirdPartyEmployee>>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(responseString));
```

Now I need to cast `obj2` as `obj1`. While I can do it manually by saying:

```
foreach (var currObj2 in obj2) 
{
    Employee  employee = null ; 

    employee .Id = currObj2 .EmpId; 
    employee.Name = currObj2.fName;
    employee.Lastname = currObj2.LName;
    employee.email = currObj2.emailID;
    obj1.add(employee); 
}
```

Is there an easier way to do this with some mapping mechanism?

While I have given an easier example, the actual scenario is much more complex with sub objects and lot more properties.

Comment: Create a constructor of Employee and pass an object of ThirdPartyEmployee like this `public Employee(ThirdPartyEmployee tpeObj){/* Assign in this constructor */}`

Comment: you can take a look automapper, [automapper starter guide](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started)

Comment: I think you should add the tag json.net. Here casting is done by json converter. so i think it should belongs to tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look to AutoMapper my friend, is what you are looking for http://automapper.org/

Here you have a old question that may help  you

[How to handle custom Properties in AutoMapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132251/how-to-handle-custom-properties-in-automapper)

Comment: Automapper is amazing.  :-)

Comment: @mrvoid - Thanks. Let me take a look . i was under the assumption that automapper needs same property names.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using NewtonSoft you can try using [JsonPropertyAttribute](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyName.htm)

```
class ThirdPartyEmployee
{
  [JsonProperty("Id")]
  string EmpId {get ; set ; }

}
```

> This will map json property of `Id` to `EmpId`

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15916121/1876572)

Comment: thanks @Eldho.. Quick question.  Can i do this for multilevel?  like for eg:  if i want to map [JsonProperty("Id.Val")] to EmpId?

Comment: I think rather than doing a multi level , place the object in ur model and try to map within the property.